# SDL Tridion TOM.NET documentation

Tags: tridion

SDL Tridion's TOM.NET API replaced the deprecated TOM (Tridion Object Model) starting in, I believe, version R5.3.

Aside from asking Stack Overflow (Exchange) questions, which documentation should we refer to when working with and learning the TOM.NET API?

So far, I've found (logins required):

- [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?c=t&action=html&resource=publist_home.html#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&lang=&action=search&query=tom.net&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1337004624749&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_81E280714DF648C192CA8BB58AF27002&pubid=SDL_Tridion_2011&publang=en-US&resource=82a02077-75a2-4d5d-acaf-63a59829473a.xml&docid=concept_81E280714DF648C192CA8BB58AF27002&filename=AccessingContentItemsTheTOM.xml&query=tom.net&scope=&tid=111cb8fb-cb37-477b-8db3-a3a15b4b4165&inner_id=&addHistory=true)
- [TridionWorld Download](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/index.aspx) (select [latest version, currently 2011 SP1](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/SDLTridion2011SP1/index.aspx) to download the "SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 TOM.NET API" chm)

I see these (plus questions on the forum), but can't tell which is *better*. **What do you use most when working with TOM.NET?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good Question and Probably most of the Tridion new developers might be wondering the same when to to use which. I would say both the documents has a different purpose and go side-by-side. API Documentation does provide information on methods and usage, SDL Live Content docs provide information is more of understanding what to use for your scenario. We do get these kind of questions when we are on boarding any new developer "Which document provides me the most information".

I refer to these simple examples to explain the differences on when to use which documentation.

1. what variables are available in package (vs) What API method to use when reading variables from package ?

Referring [Live Docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=PackageVariables.xml&docid=concept_915DDB8970C14E2A91AC0DC1B00BEA79&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_915DDB8970C14E2A91AC0DC1B00BEA79) for the first and API doc for second

2. How do I loop through the embedded fields (vs) what method I use to loop through embedded value fields ?

Referring [Live Docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=HandlingEmbeddedFieldsInAComp.xml&docid=concept_E698A4E45364484B8B1EA41E262507B7&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_E698A4E45364484B8B1EA41E262507B7) for the first and API doc for second.
I see this question with different variation keep popping up almost every month.

I know I used simple use cases, but sometimes keeping it simple is better.
Hope this information helps.

Comment: That's a great distinction, @Ram. Yeah, this time the question came up from a client. I was familiar with the older API docs, but see now how SDL Live Content provides context and the API gives details. So... we'll never have to answer this question again? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Also according to [this page](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_7A5535AA5D124768937506D674FFC102) in the documentation the TOM.NET API should be only used in Templating and Event Handlers. For third party applications you  should use the Core Service API.

Answer (score 4):

I use the API documentation, and when I really want to know more use Reflector. But that's not really advisable(?).

Comment: Using a decompiler tool like reflector may be advisable and is definitely common practice. Just keep in mind that it is illegal to decompile the DLLs, so don't go sharing the code in public forums (such as this).

Comment: A word of caution on using tools that de-compile SDL Tridon DLLs. Most license agreements specifically say that you may NOT de-compile their code. So you will likely be in violation of your agreement should you do so.